# Ajax error while uploading or removing file through managed file

Tags: ajax, files

I am getting following error while using managed file through my custom form.

> "An Ajax HTTP request terminated abnormally."

Also, I updated my jquery version to latest using jquery_update module. Still no any benefit.

Any idea on how to solve it?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Code

```
  $form['path_image'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('The uploaded image will be displayed on the page unless it is marked as "removed".'),
    '#default_value' => $current_image,
    '#upload_location' => 'public://subpage_banner/',
  );
```

Comment: Post the code for your managed file field please.

Comment: Yes code has been posted.

Comment: Code looks fine.  Are you working on localhost or via a hosting provider?  Is it possible that Fast CGI is being used?  See this article http://montenasoft.com/en/blog/500-internal-server-error-while-uploading-files-bigger-then-100kb-modfcgid-problem

Comment: @littledynamo I am on localhost. Ubuntu Server 11.04

Answer (score 0):

**MaxRequestLen** sometimes gets lowered as a result of server/module updates. Also, adding modules that add to the request length can also introduce this problem. This is why disabling modules can sometimes "fix" the problem.

See http://drupal.org/node/1015938#comment-7412202 for a solution that involves updating your vhost file, eg:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  # 50MB
  MaxRequestLen 52430000
</IfModule>
```

Or try switching from **FastCGI** to **mod_php** or **php-fpm** (if you're using FastCGI).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having lots of AJAX issues might want to try disabling the jquery_update module. It is because some modules and library scripts work with different versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this error may be permissions. Please check that the upload AJAX menu item has the right access argument `$items['file/ajax']['access arguments']` and no module else hooks and changes its default value.

Answer (score -1):

It's a jquery_update issue. Check with lower version of jquery.